# h.264 file read and parse

Tags: c++, c, h.264

how do we read a h.264 file into an array and parse it?

Comment: H264 is a video codec, when you have a video file it is usually a container, e.g. Matroksa, that includes a video stream, e.g. H264, and an audio stream, e.g. MP3.  So please reconsider your question further.

Comment: do you realy want low-level operations on raw h.264 stream?

Answer (score 1):

[ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) is the best library for audio/video encoding. It's LGPL however the h264 codec is GPL.

Comment: need customized code for the same!  no use of libraries and APIs!

Comment: exactly i need to read a h.264 file in binry format and sstore it in arrar, then parse it to get NAL units!!

Comment: found this after doing a little reading here and there..

"Basically, NAL units are separated by a simple (at least) 4-byte sequence containing a
big-endian 1, i.e. 00 00 00 01. Finding a NAL unit boundary is therefore as simple as searching for this byte sequence. The NAL unit separators themselves are discarded, only the following NAL unit content is processed further."

Comment: thanks! that proved helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at [x264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X264), an open source h.264 implementation, when starting with h.264